# UnityWebRequest can't download on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, audio, download, unitywebrequest

I want to use the sound by url,and it's can work with UnityWebRequest on PC not on Android.

Why it can't work on Android ? Did I missing something?

This is my code ,can some give me a point . Thank you!

```
  IEnumerator DownloadTheAudio()
 {
     string url = "https://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&total=1&idx=0&textlen=32&client=tw-ob&q=cat&tl=En-gb";
     using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestMultimedia.GetAudioClip(url, AudioType.MPEG)) 
     {
         yield return www.SendWebRequest();

         if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
         {
             Debug.Log(www.error);
         }
         else
         {
             AudioClip source  = DownloadHandlerAudioClip.GetContent(www);
             _audio.clip = source;
             _audio.Play();
         }

     }
```

Comment: any error messages in device log (logcat)?

Comment: It say "HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Request." on android. But nothing error in PC.

Comment: How do you call the `DownloadTheAudio` IEnumerator? Check that your script starts not too many of `DownloadTheAudio` IEnumerators.

Comment: When I push the button and  the function will call. Just one.